# RGBD-SLAM publish pointcloud Dropped 100.00% of messages

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, octomap, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,i'm new to ros,
i was able to  run offline RGBD-SLAM package from a bag file,and it
work fine,but when i try to send the result point cloud to octomap_server
through pressing 'ctrl+M'.The saved bt file is alway be the size of 18k,and
only containing one node. Here is the log info I found

```
[WARN] MessageFilter [target=/map ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.octomap_server.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

the bag file i record is follow this command:

```
rosbag record -O filename-prefix /tf /camera/rgb/image_color /camera/rgb/camera_info /camera/depth/image /camera/depth/camera_info
```

anyway,if i do online rgbdslam, all is ok!
could anyone help me out?Any suggestion is appreciate!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33034/rgbd-slam-publish-pointcloud-dropped-100.00%-of-messages/) by [David B](https://answers.ros.org/users/2267/david-b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that the timestamps of the */map -> /openni_camera* transformation are set to ros::Time::now(). The transformations */openni_camera -> /openni_rgb_optical_frame* from the bag file are old. Try running the static transformations launchfile for the kinect (roslaunch openni_camera kinect_frames.launch or something similar) before sending out the model but after you finished mapping with rgbdslam.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1